# Manipulating a Word doc with PERL and Win32::OLE works on command line, but not from a BuildForge Step

Tags: perl, win32ole, buildforge

I have functioning PERL scripts which are used to update Word documents. 
The PERL scripts are coded to work with MS Office 2003 or 2007.
The machine I'm trying to do the updates via BF on has Office 2003 on, the appropriate template is installed, the Macro Security settings have been updated.

When I run the exact command I want BF to use on the command line, it works as expected.
When I run it via a BF step I get "*** Unable to open doc  at \servername\projectname\bin\updateVer.pl line 94" (the line number is the croak in the Perl script).

The script looks like this up to the croak:

```
# enable Sanity checking and make the variable names meaningful
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;
use Win32::OLE;

# Gain access to MS Word 'wd' constants
use Win32::OLE::Const ('Microsoft Word');

use FindBin qw($RealDir);

use lib ($RealDir, "$RealDir/..", "$RealDir/../lib");

# include the common and log utilities
use SCCM::Common;
use SCCM::Logs;

# use command line inputs
use Getopt::Long qw(:config auto_abbrev permute ignore_case pass_through);

# set up logs and process logfile options
logOptions(qw(-log now));

my  $bookmark_update_result = "";
my  $update_ref_result = "";

# Get input from user

my  $path;
my  $bookmarkName;
my  $bookmarkValue;
my  $Word;
my  $newWord = 0;

GetOptions("path=s"           => \$path,
       "bookmarkName=s"   => \$bookmarkName,
   "bookmarkValue=s"  => \$bookmarkValue);

unless ( defined($path) ) 
   { croakf "%[Fail] Path and filename of SVD are required\n"; }

unless ( defined($bookmarkName) && defined($bookmarkValue) ) 
   { croakf "%[Fail] bookmarkName and bookmarkValue parameters are both required.\n"; }

# Start Word in a safer way, checking to see if user has it open first.

eval
{
  $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application');
  if (! $Word)
  {
    $newWord = 1;
    $Word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 'Quit');
  }
};

croakf "%[Fail] -- unable to start Word Engine: $@\n", Win32::OLE->LastError() if ($@ || ! $Word);

my $dispAlerts = $Word->{'DisplayAlerts'};
$Word->{'DisplayAlerts'} = wdAlertsNone;

if ($newWord)
{
  $Word->{'Visible'} = 0;
}

my $doc = $Word->Documents->Open($path) or
   croakf ("%[Fail] Unable to open doc ", Win32::OLE->LastError() );
```

The script is being called like this:
ccperl \servername\projectname\bin\updateVer.pl -path "C:\BuildForgeBuilds\BFProjectName\BFProjectName_0177\MyDocument.doc" -bookmarkName REV_Baseline -bookmarkValue My_Baseline_10.20.30

Can I get some direction to convince BF that it's OK to open my work doc?
Thank you!

Comment: It's called *"Perl"*

Comment: I'm sorry @Borodin, I don't know how your comment will assist me. We're using ccperl, because we have cc installed on all of our machines.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question; that's why it's a comment. It's supposed to assist you to spell the name of the Perl language properly. I doubt if you'd write JAVA or PYTHON, or indeed MS OFFICE?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after I removed the 'Archive' bit from the template on the machine the job was running on, BF was able to successfully run its job.

Funny I could run it directly on the server with the 'Archive' bit set on the template. But hey, I'm no longer stuck on this one.

Thanks to anybody who read my question and even considered what might have been the problem.